# Django multiple databases error with routes

Tags: django, django-migrations

I'm using 3 databases in my project:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        (postgres, read, write)...
    },
    'admission_db': {
        (postgres, read, write)...
    },
    'journals_db': {
        (mysql, read only)...
    }
}
DATABASE_ROUTERS = [
    'main.lib.DbRouter.DbRouter',
]
```

wrote db router:

```
class DbRouter:
...

    def allow_migrate(self, db, app_label, model=None, **hints):
        if db == 'admission_db':
            if model and model._meta.app_label == 'admission':
                return True
            return app_label == 'admission'
        elif db == 'journals_db':
            return False
        return None
```

when i make migrate command

```
python manage.py migrate admission --database admission_db
```

it migrates normally, but when i try to make

```
python manage.py migrate,
```

it throws

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: admission_educationform
```

because of it i can make make migrate on other apps.
(python 3.5.2, django 1.10.5)
what can be cause of problem?

Comment: `$ python manage.py migrate --fake` solved this issue and I can migrate changes in another apps, but i hope, there is another solution, that make `$ python manage.py migrate` to migrate all apps without database and app options

Answer (score 0):

Added check of db used in magration:

```
def allow_migrate(self, db, app_label, model=None, **hints):
    if db == 'default':
        if app_label == 'admission':
            return False
        elif model and model._meta.app_label == 'admission':
            return False
    if db == 'admission_db':
        if model and model._meta.app_label == 'admission':
            return True
        return app_label == 'admission'
    elif db == 'journals_db':
        return False
    return None
```

So, i should launch 2 migrate commands:

```
python migrate admission
python migrate
```

Now it works fine.